# Append child view outside parent view in DOM in Backbone.js app

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

In my backbone app I create a popover in parent view and add it to the DOM like this

```
afterRender: function() {
    this.$el.append(
      new Popover.Views.Default({ 
        stick:'right', 
        offsetTop: 3, 
        offsetRight: 5, 
        content: "Foo", 
        reference: this.$el
     }).render().$el
   );
},
toggle: function(){  
  app.vent.trigger('popover34:toggle');
}
```

However the popover is appended to its parent view. The parent view is a link and this causes some css issues in the popover.

My question is, is it safe to do something like:

```
afterRender: function() {
    $('body').append(
      new Popover.Views.Default({ 
        stick:'right', 
        offsetTop: 3, 
        offsetRight: 5, 
        content: "Foo", 
        reference: this.$el
     }).render().$el
   );
}
```

Or is there a way to set it just beside the parent view? The problem is that when I toggle the popover it will be added to the DOM multiple times.

Comment: You never remove the popover view?

Comment: @muistooshort no, I just hide/show it

Comment: So you keep creating new ones, never remove any of them, and wonder why there's a problem? Why not destroy them when the popover closes? Then you could append them to `<body>` (where they probably belong) and everything would be okay, no?

Comment: @muistooshort exactly what I am working at now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To second (and hopefully clarify) Isaac's answer here, your 'parent' view should be in one region, the `Popover` view should be in another region.

Brian Mann has done an [excellent set of videos](http://www.backbonerails.com/series) on Marionette.js and good application design, [one specifically that demonstrates your exact scenario](http://www.backbonerails.com/screencasts/building-dialogs-with-custom-regions).

Good luck,
Aaron

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using Marionette. Using Marionette, one way to handle this is with [regions](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.region.md). From the docs:

> Regions provide a consistent way to manage your views and show / close them in your application. They use a jQuery selector to show your views in the correct place.

You can put your region anywhere you like and trigger it using the Event Aggregator. In addition, it automatically closes old views so you don't end up with zombies.